# How do i get part of string after a special character?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column where i pickup increasing numbering values, and their format is xx_yy
so the first is 1_0, second 1_1 and so forth,  no we are at  23_31

I want to get the right side of the string, and i am already getting the left side correctly.
using

```
newActionId = Left(lastActionID, (Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("_", lastActionID, 1) - 1))
```

i wish to do the following, human writing below

```
nextSubid = entire stringvalue AFTER special character "_"
```

I tried just switching left to right, didnt go so well, do you have a suggestion?

Comment: `Split("23_31","_")(0)` will give `23` and `Split("23_31","_")(1)` will give `31`

Comment: ohhh did not know about split, that is amazing.  Will give that a go straight away.

Comment: It works,,  drop an answer, that is amazing.  Learned something new AGAIN today..  <3 Stackoverflow

Comment: Fun little alternative to get your first value: `newActionId  = Val(lastActionID)`. Will return a `Variant/Double` type variable.

Comment: and yet another way :) `Debug.Print Right(id, (InStrRev(id, "_", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function) to get the relevant text.

> Syntax: Split(expression, [ delimiter, [ limit, [ compare ]]])

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim id As String
    Dim beforeSplChr As String
    Dim afterSplChr As String

    id = "23_31"

    beforeSplChr = Split(id, "_")(0)
    afterSplChr = Split(id, "_")(1)

    Debug.Print beforeSplChr
    Debug.Print afterSplChr
End Sub
```

**Another way**

```
Debug.Print Left(id, (InStrRev(id, "_", -1) - 1)) '<~~ Left Part
Debug.Print Right(id, (InStrRev(id, "_", -1) - 1)) '<~~ Right Part
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though Siddharth Rout has given what can probably be considered a better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60485158/9290986), I felt that this was worth adding:

To get the second part of the string using your original method, you would want to use [the `Mid` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function) in place of [`Left`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/left-function), rather than trying to use [`Right`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/right-function).

> **Mid(string, start, *[ length ]*)**
>   Returns *length* characters from *string*, starting at the *start* position
>   If *length* is omitted, then will return characters from the *start* position until the end of the string

```
newActionId = Mid(lastActionID, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("_", lastActionID, 1) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun (`Split` is the way to go here), an alternative way using regular expressions:

```
Sub Test()

Dim str As String: str = "23_31"

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "\d+"
    Debug.Print .Execute(str)(0) 'Left Part
    Debug.Print .Execute(str)(1) 'Right Part
End With

End Sub
```

Btw, as per my comment, your first value could also be achieved through:

```
Debug.Print Val(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Split function of string is very usefull for this type of query.
Like:

```
String s = "23_34";
String left = s.split("_")[0];
String right = s.split("_")[1];

Or you can also use combination of indexOf and substring method together.
String left = s.substring(0,s.indexOf('_')+1)
String right = s.substring(s.indexOf('_'));
```